# Publishing a node to a specific page?

Tags: drupal

I have created a new content type "Quote". Now the user should be able to link a specific "Quote" to a specific page where the user wants the quote to be shown.

Is this possible?

thx

Comment: If I where you i would be a little bit more specific. Write down as much as possible when you state a question.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the 'nodereference' field type provided by the [CCK module](http://drupal.org/project/cck). It allows you to add one or more fields to a content type that can reference other nodes.